# Using Boruta package efficiently in R

Tags: r

I have a list of variables, say v1,v2,v3,v4....v25 in my dataset df. My predictor variable is Sales. While using Boruta package for feature selection I am writing:

```
Boruta(Sales ~ ., data=na.omit(df), doTrace=2)
```

If I want to manually remove one variable, say v1 that I know does not have any significance, I write:

```
Boruta(Sales ~ .-v1, data=na.omit(df), doTrace=2)
```

What should I do to remove multiple variables? Like v2,v3 and v4?
Also, what can be done if I want to keep a few variables for the checking with Boruta, say 20 variables out of 50?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Boruta uses the usual 'formula' format, right? So you can keep chaining '-[variable]' together for as many as you can be bothered typing out, eg `lm(mpg~.-cyl-drat,mtcars)`

The dot means 'everything', so if there's more stuff you want to omit that stuff you want to keep, leave off the dot and add stuff in instead of taking it away, eg `lm(mpg~cyl+drat,mtcars)`

You can also create a formula from a string, so you have the option of getting R to build the formula for you

```
vars <- c("cyl","drat")#whatever your process is for getting these
myf <- as.formula(paste0(c("mpg~",vars[1],paste0('+',vars[2:length(vars)])),collapse=""))
lm(formula=myf,mtcars)
```

Although it might be easier to keep using the dot and just pass a data frame with only the cols you want (using dplyr select or similar)

Comment: It is safer to create a formula object like `myf <- as.formula(paste("mpg ~ ", paste(vars, collapse= "+")))`. Some packages check on this and will fail if the formula passed to them is just a character string instead of a formula object.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the above answer is well and truly very complete and explains the solution to your question.

But from my experience, it is best if you pass the filtered `dataframe` into `Boruta` because I would imagine you would like to roll with the results of `Boruta`?

Say, if I am dealing with 52 variables and I would like to know which variables actually add information about a specific class, I would use `Boruta`.

Again from experience, if you are not interested in 20 of the 52 variables anyways, I cannot see why you would make a smaller `dataframe` by filtering those redundant variables so your code would have higher readability.

As previously mentioned, you can use the `dplyr` package to select out the variables you are not going to send to `Boruta`:

```
df_filtered <- df %>% select(-c(var1, var2, var3))
```